# Navigation bar links

Tags: html, css

I've seen many tutorials on how to create a navigation bar, and I have the basics down, but what none of them explain is how to link them to a page with the same navigation bar, but different content. Right now, for the bar links, I'm copying and pasting the code of the page into another html file and changing the content, but this is very inefficient because if I want to change something in the bar I'd have to go through each and every file.

There must be a better way to do this - how?
I'm using brackets to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you evolve into the next level of development and it's very exciting :)

Templating Engines are used for this exactly.

Say you had a Navigation Component that you want to have on 20+ pages, you won't want to change every single instance each time you want to modify it, right?

If you use templating engines you can create a navigation component, let's call it `nav.html`, and then in your base template.. call it `main.html` you can render the `nav.html` and it will be as if you wrote the code in the `main.html`..

However, if you want to change something, all you have to do is change it once in `nav.html`, and it will change everywhere else automatically.

If this doesn't make sense, it's fine.

**Dust** is a great engine you can start learning. It will allow you to create much more dynamic applications and websites and templating is beyond useful when you have many pages.

You can start reading up on the documentation [here](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/getting-started/), and try to understand what the fundamentals of templating engines are. If you choose you don't like Dustjs, have a look at this: https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

It will tell you what to use based on your exact needs!

I hope this helps and leads you to a new way of thinking, it's a big step but really worth it.

Enjoy! :)

**EDIT**

Another good pure HTML templating engine I've found is [PureJS](https://beebole.com/pure/), have a look at this one too!